# Constructor keeps disappearing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, datacontext

I have a c# program that interacts with an sql database.  I added the database using Server Explorer, and now have a dbml file to interact with it.  The name is MasterDatabase.dbml.  The IDE generated several overloaded constructors in MasterDatabase.designer.cs.

I added another overloaded constructor that takes no parameters (every one the computer generated takes at least one parameter).  The code works perfectly with this overloaded constructor, but it will occasionally disappear!  The constructor will be there for days, and then one day I will run my code and get a bunch of errors saying that there is no constructor that takes 0 arguments.  I will then go back to MasterDatabase.designer.cs, and my constructor is no longer there.  So I add it again, and the cycle repeats itself.

Has anyone experienced this before?  And more importantly, how do I fix it so that my constructor stops disappearing?

I did not post any code, because this is a general question, and I don't think my specific code will help solve the problem, but let me know if you need to see any of it and I will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generally don't want to modify those generated classes directly. Those classes may be rebuilt without warning. I don't have much experience in this, but I believe those generated classes are `partial` classes. Create a new .cs file completely, with the same class name (including the partial keyword) and add the constructor there.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks!  I will separate it out that way and return if any more problems arise.  I don't expect there to be any more issues though, because your answer makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are editing a generated file. WPF uses `partial` classes to seperate YOUR code from GENERATED code. You can create 'partial' classes of your own, although this serves no particular use other than organization of code. To get to the point, whatever code you write in a `partial` class can be rewritten in any other `partial` class file, so long as the classes are same. So take your overloaded constructor and put it into a NON-GENERATED file. This will prevent the generator from editing any changes you have made in that file. If the code worked sometimes in the generated `partial` file, it should always work if put into a non-generated `partial` file, because the code is not altered by Visual.